# Issues with CSV file handling (Writing And Reading)

Tags: python, csv

Sup geeks! As a very beginner to CSV files and modules, I am facing some issues while running my codes. At some point, it is acting a bit weird. My objective is to write a program to create a file `voter.csv` containing voter id, voter name, and voter age. And to read the file and display the number of records.

The code I've worked out is given below:

```py
import csv

f = open('voter.csv','w',newline='')
obj = csv.writer(f)
field = ['VID','VNAME','VAGE']
obj.writerow(field)
n = int(input("Enter the number"))
for i in range(n):
    c = int(input("Enter the voter id"))
    nm = input("Name")
    a = int(input("Voter age"))
    x = [c,nm,a]
    obj.writerow(x)
f.close()

f = open('voter.csv')
a = csv.reader(f)
for i in a:
    print(i)
m = 0
for i in a:
    if a.line_num == 1:
        continue
    else:
        m = m+1
print(m)
f.close()
```

Which always gives the number of records as `0` instead of giving the total number of records which was added. After all, I decided to work out what was wrong and I found out that the second *for loop* after the first one is not working... Why is that happening? How can this be fixed?

This question was edited for its betterment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Once you iterate through a file iterator, it is exhausted and you need to reopen the file or seek to the start to read it again.

Comment: Or keep track of the number of lines as you're iterating through it the first time so you don't need to re-read the whole thing.  Or just use `n` since that has to be the same as the `m` you're trying to get.

Comment: Also CSV is just a comma-separated values file, so you can just read it like a normal text file and then count the line minus the first header line

Comment: @TechieGeeke If `a` is a `csv.reader` object, you can know everything about its attributes and methods by looking a [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#reader-objects) - that should always be your first reflex.

Comment: Yes, but the ultimate goal is to get you to be self-reliant, so... You got the advice you needed! ;) SO is also a great place to find answers that can't be found in the documentation...

Comment: Apparently you don't…at least not correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will do what you want, in terms of printing out each row of the file as well as the total number of lines:

```
import csv

n = int(input("Enter the number"))

with open('voter.csv','w',newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['VID','VNAME','VAGE'])
    for _ in range(n):
        writer.writerow([
            input("Enter the voter id"),
            input("Name"),
            input("Voter age")
        ])

m = 0
with open('voter.csv') as f:
    for m, i in enumerate(csv.reader(f)):
        print(i)

print("Total lines:", m)
```

If you want to actually re-read the file, the simplest thing is to re-`open` it:

```
with open('voter.csv') as f:
    for i in csv.reader(f):
        print(i)

with open('voter.csv') as f:
    m = sum(1 for _ in f)

print("Total lines:", m - 1)
```

Each `open` call gets you a fresh iterator that starts at the beginning of the file.  Each line you read from `f` (or whatever you named the object you got from `open()`) advances the iterator through the file.  Starting a new `for` loop over the file doesn't give you a new iterator, it just picks up where the current one left off.

The source of your confusion might be that a file iterator behaves differently from a list -- a list is not itself an iterator, it's an iterable that can create new iterators on command.  Every time you start a new iteration over a list you're implicitly creating a new iterator, as if you'd re-opened a file.